# Every left-invariant top form is right invariant

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

This problem is from Introduction to Manifolds (Tu), 18.9 (p. 209). I understood parts (a)-(c), but not (d).

> Let $G$ be a compact, connected Lie Group with Lie algebra
> $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $l_a$ and $r_a$ be left and right multiplication
> by a, respectively. Define $f:\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$
> by  $$f(a) = r_a^* \circ l_{a^{-1}}^*,$$
>
> where $()^*$ denotes the pullback. As the continuous image of a
> compact connected set G, the set $f(G) \subset \mathbb{R^x}$ is
> compact and connected.
>
> Prove that $f(G) = 1$.

In the earlier parts of the problem, I proved that $f$ was smooth, a group homomorphism, and $f(a) =\det(\operatorname{Ad}(a^{-1}))$, where $\operatorname{Ad}$ is the adjoint.

As a homomorphism, $f(e)$ = 1. Then $f(G) = [a,b]$, with $0 < a \le 1 \le b$ since it is compact and connected in $\mathbb{R^x}$. How do I show $a = b = 1$?

Comment: You should edit this so that it makes sense. What domain and range does $f$ actually have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $f$ you define is first a map from the Lie algebra into itself, then it miraculously becomes real valued, which seems a bit fishy to me.

The proof of the statement you want to show which I'm aware of (from Spivaks comprehensive introduction to Differential Geometry, Vol. 1, Proposition 10.20) goes as follows, and seems to be what the construction you wrote down is aming at:

Let $\omega\neq 0$ be some $n$-form.
If $a\in G$ then $r^*_a \omega$ is a left invariant form (since $\omega$ is), so $$ r^*_a\omega = h(a) \omega$$ for some unique real number $h(a)\neq 0$.
Because of $$r^*_a\circ r^*_b = (r_{ab})^*$$
we have $$ h(ab) = h(a)h(b)$$
So $h(G) $ is a compact connected Lie subgroup of $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ which implies $h(G) = \{1\}$

Comment: Your last sentence is exactly what I'm trying to understand -- I understand that $h(G) \subset R^{x}$ is compact and connected, but don't understand why this implies $h(G) = {1}$

Comment: @IsaacR24 It is a compact connected *Lie subgroup*.

Comment: @IsaacR24 Just look at what happens to $x^n$ if $x\in h(G)$ is not $=1$ and $n$ becomes large.

Comment: Suppose that $h(G) \ne 1$. If $x \in h(G)$ then $x^n \in h(G)$, where $x = f(a)$ for some $ a \in G$. It follows that $f(a)^n = x^n = f(a^n) \in h(G)$ I still don't see the contradiction...but think I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Ah maybe I have it. Let $a_n = x^n$ with $x \in h(G)$. By compactness, ${a_n}$ must have a convergent subsequence. This is true only if $a_n = 1$ for infinitely many $n$...but I would need this to be true for all $n$. Hmm..

Comment: @IsaacR24 $x^n \rightarrow 0 $ if $x<1$ and $\rightarrow \infty $ if $x>1$. Also, the equation $x^n = 1$ has only one solution in the set of positive real numbers.

Comment: Ah of course -- ok got it now. Thanks for patiently explaining!